# Calling ExecutorService after some interval of time

Tags: executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

Is their a way to schedule a thread pool using ExecutorService , in lines similar to thread.sleep()

My current code looks something like

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(poolSize);
 public void run() { 
 try {
     pool.execute(new Worker());
 }
```

But I want to call the run method, only after some time interval. Can someone let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Sample code

```
pool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
pool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Thread(), 100,200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The 'run()' method of the 'Thread()' class will be called at a regular intervals of 200 milliseconds & its first execution will be after 100 ms