# Java - condition statement based on milliseconds

Tags: java, date, time, conditional-statements

Quick question here, I need to execute a certain method only after a specific time period has passed (in milliseconds):

```
static double incrTrueBinaryErr = 62.5;
static double incrTrueBinaryMov = 31.25;
static double incr01001 = 360000;
static double incr_1101 = 125;
static double incr05008 = 3600000;
static double incr10004 = 1024000;
static double incr22000 = 1000;
static double incr22001 = 1000;

Date currDate;

    while (true)
    {
    currDate = new Date();

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incrTrueBinaryErr)
        //do stuff

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incrTrueBinaryMov)
        //do stuff

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incr01001)
        //do stuff

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incr_1101)
        //do stuff

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incr05008)
        //do stuff

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incr10004)
        //do stuff

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incr22000)
        //do stuff

    if (currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incr22001)
        //do stuff

    }
```

However, my program never hits any of these because of how specific the time intervals are.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Try to get the time outside the `While` loop...or else use sheduled executor [Check this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988664/calling-executorservice-after-some-interval-of-time)..

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to run several times, each with a different delay?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of expression `currDate.getTime() == currDate.getTime() + incr01001` will evaluate to `true` only if `incr01001 == 0`. For the same reason `x == x + y` only when `y == 0`.

Comment: So what your saying is, I would require a wait() or sleep() command in order to reach any of those increments?

Comment: Depending on what you want. Do you want a part of code to be executed at a particular point of time? or when a particular time passed after previous block execution?

Comment: I need to call a method that invokes a new Date() command, that assigns to a time field of a value written to another file, so it calls a method then creates a new timestamp that hopefully is increment time away from currDate

Comment: But why do you need those double varaibles in the first place? Why don't you just do stuff, then do stuff and then do stuff?

Comment: I need specific timestamps in the //doStuff lines

Comment: You need a particular Timestamp when you execute some block of code? Why don't you just create it at the moment while you are executing the block?

Comment: This... might actually work, if i manually edit the timerstamps by just adding the increments to them... lety me try

Answer (score 1):

**To execute a certain method only after a specific time period has passed (in milliseconds):**

You can use `Thread.sleep(long milliseconds)` method to do that.

```
try{
  Thread.sleep(5000);//for 5 seconds
} catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, this wouldn't have quite the functionality they want. This assumes they know how much time has to pass, when what should happen should depend on the time. This could only wait on one of his actions in his `if` blocks, rather than check them all.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the time outside your while block first:

```
Date date = new Date();
while (true)
{
  currDate = new Date();

  if (currDate.getTime() == date.getTime() + incrTrueBinaryErr)
    //do stuff
  //etc.
}
```

This way the while loop doesn't keep reassigning the date.

It might also be a bit too specific as you say, so for your `if` block maybe:

```
long timeDifference = date.getTime()+incrTrueBinaryErr-currDate.getTime();

if (Math.abs(timeDifference)<5l)
  //do stuff
```

If the new time is within 5 milliseconds of what you want, "do stuff".